# I cannot compile and run Java package in MacOS.Can some one help me how to compile?

Tags: java

```
package world;
public class ackage{
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("HELLO hi");

}   
}
```

I get some kind of error.
the error is

```
Error: Could not find or load main class ackage
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: world/ackage (wrong name: ackage)
```

Comment: You should also add the command line (or description) how you run the program when you get the error.

Comment: For such problems the directory layout (which file is in which directory) is important.

Answer (score 0):

The name of java file and class name must be same. I think that is problem.

Comment: As this is guessing, you should post it as a comment.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will improve.